# Is a transit visa required at Abu Dhabi airport for South African citizens?

Tags: visas, south-african-citizens, abu-dhabi

We are SA citizens traveling with Etihad Airlines.
We have a 10 hour layover on our way back to SA from Thailand and I would like to book into one of the express hotels situated opposite the terminal within the airport.

Do I need a visa for this?

Answer (score 1):

The only hotel for which you don't need a visa is the [airport hotel](http://www.abudhabiairport.ae/english/airport-information/airport-facilities/airport-hotels/airport-hotel.aspx).

For the hotel you are referring to, you will need a transit visa. The good news is, Etihad can arrange these for you very easily. Once you have your reservation, contact your Etihad airlines office and they will arrange for a visa for your traveling party. Make sure you contact them well in advance.

Comment: The last time I looked, Etihad could also arrange for the visa under "Manage my booking" on their web site.

Comment: Its outsourced unfortunately to TTS (here is the [direct link](https://www.ttsuaevisas.com/en-za/applying-for-visa-online/)); and they are not the most reliable. It is a lot easier to simply visit the office if there is one close by.